# JavaScript object destructuring on an already declared variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am getting an esLint warning on the below to use object destructuring.

Can I do this reassigning an already declared variable as per the below example, or should I just ignore the esLint warning.

```
let testA = 0;

if (condition) {
    testA = myObj.testA;
    // cannot do 'const { testA } = myObj;' because I have already declared testA in the above scope
}
```

Comment: Can't do it with `const` and use same variable name ... no

Comment: `let testA = {myObj}; if (!condition) testA = 0;` :-P (Joking.) Yes, you can ignore eslint here, using destructuring is possible but not much of an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was thinking I could do what is suggested below, but wasn't sure how/why that would be an improvement, other than to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score -3):

So const is unchangeable declaration. You can't assign a variable which is use before.

Replace

```
const { testA } = myObj;
```

with

```
const { testA: testATemp } = myObj; //this is assignment while destructing
console.log(testATemp);
```